# MVC Return Fields to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I've got a controller to retrieve and return values for my drop down, and a second, that when an option from the dropdown is selected, uses the values (Title and ID) in an API Request.

### Controllers

```
public ActionResult GetEpics()
        {
            //Code to retrieve list
            Epics = new GetEpicsViewModel();
            Epics.Epics = epicsList;

            return View(Epics);
        }



 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Build(GetEpicsViewModel epic)

            {
                GetEpicsViewModel epicTest = epic;
                //API Request
                return View();
            }
```

This is displayed in my drop down list as below:

### View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Build", "GetEpics", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <label for="input_OutputType"> Process: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Epics, "Id", "Title")) </label>                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                }
```

This works fine, but how would I then go about passing both the Title and ID to my controller?
I can pass the ID through fine, but cant figure out how to pass the Title as well.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGM3.png)

### Models

```
public class DevOpsEpic
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }            
        public string Title { get; set; }            
        public string Description { get; set; }  

    }
```

and

```
 public class GetEpicsViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<DevOpsEpic> Epics { get; set; }
    }
```

Realise this is probably a really simple answer, but just cant figure it out!

Comment: You can Title similar to ID

Comment: Add title filed in views than post automatic data mapped

Comment: You would have to use a bit of javascript to get the value and text

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that, so when your dropdown is changed, set title value in hidden file.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Build", "GetEpics", FormMethod.Post))
  {
       <label for="input_OutputType"> Process: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Epics, "Id", "Title"),new { name = "Id" }) </label>
       <input type="hidden" id="Title" name="Title" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  }

$('#dropdownId').change(function(){

   $('#Title').val($('#dropdownId option:selected').text());

});
```